# Creating Leaflet maps in R; extracting results to a data frame of points that fall within a defined radius

Tags: r, leaflet

I am creating maps using the `leaflet` package in R and I would like to be able to extract the data points that fall within a defined radius.

In my example below, I have created a map with a 5 KM radius (shaded in green). The mock dataframe being used here has coordinates of five sites; two of them fall within the radius whilst the other three fall well outside of the radius. Here is the code and output:-

```
library(leaflet)

markerdata<-data.frame(Location = c("Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3", "Site 4", "Site 5"),
                       Lon = c(174.768, 180.760, 174.764, 174.740,171.720),
                       Lat = c(-36.852,-37.20,-36.832,-39.45,-32.10))



m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  #addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")%>%
  addCircles(lng=174.768, 
             lat=-36.852,
             radius = 5 * 1000,
             col = "green")%>%
  addCircles(data = markerdata,
             lng = ~Lon,
             lat = ~Lat,
             col = "red")

m  # Print the map
```

[image: map, zoomed out]

(zoomed in)

[image: map zoomed in]

Is there a way to extract the data points to a dataframe, and having a logical column which tells us whether the data points fall within the shaded green area (i.e. if within radius == TRUE, if outside radius == FALSE), along with complementary information i.e. Location name?

Comment: Look at  `st_intersection` from `sf``.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```r
library(geosphere)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

markerdata<-data.frame(Location = c("Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3", "Site 4", "Site 5"),
                       Lon = c(174.768, 180.760, 174.764, 174.740,171.720),
                       Lat = c(-36.852,-37.20,-36.832,-39.45,-32.10))


lng <- 174.768
lat <- -36.852
radius <- 5

markerdata %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(distance_km = map2_dbl(Lon, Lat, ~({
    distm(c(lng, lat),c(..1, ..2),  fun =  distHaversine) %>% as.numeric() / 1000
  })),
  is_there = ifelse(distance_km < radius, TRUE, FALSE))
#> Warning in .pointsToMatrix(y): longitude > 180
#> Warning in .pointsToMatrix(p2): longitude > 180
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   Location   Lon   Lat distance_km is_there
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <lgl>   
#> 1 Site 1    175. -36.9        0    TRUE    
#> 2 Site 2    181. -37.2      534.   FALSE   
#> 3 Site 3    175. -36.8        2.25 TRUE    
#> 4 Site 4    175. -39.4      289.   FALSE   
#> 5 Site 5    172. -32.1      598.   FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>